# LightopenID for CI - Could not connect to google

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, gmail, openid

I have followed [this](http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/) guide (with modifications) to use lightopenid for my CI system login.

I downloaded and placed my openid.php file on my root folder (the one where application, assets, etc. folders are).

In the login page, I have this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('logingoogle/gmail_login');?>" target="_blank">Login using gmail</a>
```

The code inside my applications/controllers/logingoogle.php is this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Logingoogle extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function index(){}
function gmail_login(){
    require_once 'openid.php';
    $openid = new LightOpenID(base_url());
    $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
    $openid->required = array(
                                 'namePerson/first'
                                ,'namePerson/last'
                                ,'contact/email'
    );
    $openid->returnUrl = base_url('logingoogle/after_login');
    $openid->authUrl();
}
function after_login(){
    require_once 'openid.php';
    $openid = new LightOpenID(base_url());
    $login_response = '';
    $email = '';
    $first = '';
    if ($openid->mode) {
        if ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
            $login_response = "User has canceled authentication!";
        } elseif($openid->validate()) {
            $data = $openid->getAttributes();
            $email = $data['contact/email'];
            $first = $data['namePerson/first'];
        } else {
            $login_response = "The user has not logged in";
        }
    }
    else{
        $login_response = "Go to index page to log in.";
    }
    $data['user_details'] = array(
                                     'login_response'   => $login_response
                                    ,'identity'         => $openid->identity
                                    ,'email'            => $email
                                    ,'first'            => $first
    );
    $this->load->view('after_login',$data);
}
}
```

Now, when I clcik the "Login using gmail" link, it opens a new blank tab which loads for 5 minutes (I've timed it). After 5 minutes, this error is displayed in plain text:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Failed connect to www.google.com:443; No error' in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\openid.php:229 Stack trace: #0 C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\openid.php(360): LightOpenID->request_curl('https: //www.goo...', 'GET', Array, true) #1 C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\openid.php(499): LightOpenID->request('https: //www.goo...', 'GET', Array, true) #2 C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\openid.php(671): LightOpenID->discover('https: //www.goo...') #3 C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\application\controllers\logingoogle.php(30): LightOpenID->authUrl() #4 [internal function]: Logingoogle->gmail_login() #5 C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\index.php(206): require_once('C:\WebServer\Ap...') #7 {main} thrown in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\ETO\openid.php on line 229

Has anyone out there encountered a similar error before? What am I doing wrong? I could not decipher the error message given to me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Google requires API Credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) so i suggest you to use "OpenIDConnectClientGoogle.class.php" to convert your code. Or use [this](https://drupal.org/project/openid_connect) OpenId library

It contains referred php file.

If you want to more reading about Google's last changes, please look at [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)